# Code is not working online but working in localhost

Tags: javascript

Hello The below function contains an image which is working properly in localhost but whenever i m uploading that to cpanel its not working online.

Here is the code:

```
function CONshowElements()
{
var Construction = "<center><img src='images/SCALE Construction.PNG'></center><br>The construction company with several years of experience in projects valued over millions of USD having Service and Quality with satisfaction and appreciation of the clients.";
document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = Construction;
}
```

Comment: Does `images/SCALE Construction.PNG` exist in your live environment? Have you checked the console for errors? What do you mean 'not working'? **Be more specific**.

Comment: not working means its showing the text but not the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server might run under Linux, while your localhost probably runs under Windows. 
That means image file-names are case-sensitive.

Check if your image-name is actually

```
SCALE Construction.PNG
```

and not

```
SCALE Construction.png
```

If that's the case, you get a 404 on the development console. 
Also, that whitespace in the file-name is a very bad idea...

Comment: *Also, that whitespace in the file-name is a very bad idea* -- Can you back that up?

Comment: @George: Not actually, but if it's in src, it should probably be URL-encoded. Same thing goes if it's not an ASCII character. One bug (or rather incompleteness) in the server/fastcgi-or-isapi-layer/browser/operatingsystem, and boom, 404.

Comment: I agree, maybe put that in your question? I think saying whitespace in a file name is a bad idea is a blanket statement and could be perceived in many different ways, that's all (: